# Amcharts to display only even numbers in Y-axis

Tags: amcharts, amcharts5

I am trying to have only even numbers from 0 and up on the Y-axis of a amcharts5 Line chart but i cannot figure it out how to.

Example: if the biggest value is 5 my Y-axis should how: 0, 2, 4, 6.

Is it possible to achieve this?

What I'm currently having:

```
  var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(
  am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
    min: 0,
    maxPrecision: 0,
    maxDeviation: 0.1,
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {})
  })
);
```

Result:
[image]

What I need to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to play with the `minGridDistance` property referenced [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/reference/iaxisrenderersettings/#minGridDistance_property)?

```
var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
  renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {
    minGridDistance: 20
  })
}));
```

Full example:

```js
am5.ready(function () {

  var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

  var chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {}));

  var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {})
  }));

  var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {
      minGridDistance: 20 // Play with it and see what happens...
    })
  }));

  var series = chart.series.push(am5xy.LineSeries.new(root, {
    name: "Series",
    xAxis: xAxis,
    yAxis: yAxis,
    valueXField: "valueX",
    valueYField: "valueY"
  }));
  
  var data = [],
      valueX = 0,
      valueY = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    data.push({ valueX: i, valueY: i });
  }

  series.data.setAll(data);

});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```